# Sencha ExtJS setting automatically unique id`s

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I've had a problem that's been bothering me for some time:

In an ExtJS application whose UI is created with Sencha Architect, all widgets should have unique IDs.

Why?
1. to be able to assign labels in the previously selected language at runtime

2. in order to be able to address the elements clearly in automatic tests

I achieve both goals if I assign the ID manually....but this is quite time-consuming in the long run. Does anyone know of a better solution?

Thank you,

Felix

Comment: Not necessary extjs automatically assign unique IDs to each component which is rendered.On top of this what is your expectation ?

Comment: For automation you don't need IDs you can use other things for your query such as xtypes, names and other things. Otherwise I don't think there is method setID(), so I think such thing needs to be done manually.

Comment: My expectation (or better: my dream) was a to get a smart way to have application wide unique id`s for each widget...without setting them manually.

But i see there seems not such a way.

Thanks for your help!